How to resolve the error Method Not Allowed (POST) in Django?
I'm creating a POS application in Django. Currently I'm using the template bellow for adding items to a current order, modifying quantities, deletes some items that are unecessary to be in the current order, and finaly, after adding all needed items, to click on the Checkout button for validation.
{% load multiply %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Order Details</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'posApp:home' %}">POS System</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'posApp:category_list' %}">Categories</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'posApp:order_list' %}">Order list</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'posApp:create_order' %}">Create Order</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'posApp:add_category' %}">Add Category</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'posApp:product_list' %}">Products list</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'posApp:add_product' %}">Add Product</a>
                </li>
                
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <h1>Order {{ order.id }}</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <form id="add-item-form" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="barcode">Barcode</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="barcode" name="barcode" placeholder="Enter Barcode" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" min="1" value="1" required>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Product</button>
                </form>
                <div id="error-message" class="text-danger mt-2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2>Current Order</h2>
                <ul class="list-group" id="order-items">
                    {% for item in order.items.all %}
                        <li class="list-group-item" id="item-{{ item.id }}">
                            {{ item.product.name }} -
                            <input type="number" class="form-control d-inline item-quantity" style="width: 70px;" value="{{ item.quantity }}" min="1" data-item-id="{{ item.id }}" data-order-id="{{ order.id }}">
                            x {{ item.product.price }} + Tax: {{ item.tax_amount }} = <span class="item-total">{{ item.price|add:item.tax_amount }}</span>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove-item" data-order-id="{{ order.id }}" data-item-id="{{ item.id }}">Remove</button>
                        </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
                <p class="mt-3"><strong>Total (before tax):</strong> <span id="total-amount">{{ order.total_amount }}</span></p>
                <p class="mt-3"><strong>Total Tax:</strong> <span id="total-tax">{{ order.total_tax_amount }}</span></p>
                <p class="mt-3"><strong>Total (with tax):</strong> <span id="total-with-tax">{{ order.total_amount_with_tax }}</span></p>
                <a href="{% url 'posApp:checkout' order.id %}" class="btn btn-success">Checkout</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            function updateOrderTotals(totalWithoutTax, totalTax, totalWithTax) {
                $('#total-amount').text(totalWithoutTax.toFixed(2));
                $('#total-tax').text(totalTax.toFixed(2));
                $('#total-with-tax').text(totalWithTax.toFixed(2));
            }

            $('#add-item-form').on('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var barcode = $('#barcode').val();
                var quantity = parseInt($('#quantity').val());

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "{% url 'posApp:add_to_order' order.id %}",
                    data: {
                        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
                        'barcode': barcode,
                        'quantity': quantity
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response.success) {
                            var itemElement = $('#item-' + response.order_item_id);
                            if (itemElement.length) {
                                itemElement.find('.item-quantity').val(response.quantity);
                                itemElement.find('.item-total').text((response.quantity * parseFloat(response.price)).toFixed(2));
                            } else {
                                var itemHTML = '<li class="list-group-item" id="item-' + response.order_item_id + '">' +
                                    response.product_name + ' - ' +
                                    '<input type="number" class="form-control d-inline item-quantity" style="width: 70px;" value="' + response.quantity + '" min="1" data-item-id="' + response.order_item_id + '" data-order-id="{{ order.id }}">' +
                                    ' x ' + parseFloat(response.price).toFixed(2) + ' + Tax: ' + parseFloat(response.tax_amount).toFixed(2) + ' = <span class="item-total">' + (response.quantity * parseFloat(response.price)).toFixed(2) + '</span>' +
                                    '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove-item" data-order-id="{{ order.id }}" data-item-id="' + response.order_item_id + '">Remove</button>' +
                                    '</li>';
                                $('#order-items').append(itemHTML);
                            }
                            updateOrderTotals(parseFloat(response.total_without_tax), parseFloat(response.total_tax), parseFloat(response.total_with_tax));
                            $('#barcode').val('');
                            $('#quantity').val(1);
                            $('#error-message').text('');
                        } else {
                            $('#error-message').text(response.error);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        $('#error-message').text('An error occurred: ' + error);
                    }
                });
            });

            $(document).on('change', 'input.item-quantity', function() {
                var itemId = $(this).data('item-id');
                var orderId = $(this).data('order-id');
                var quantity = parseInt($(this).val());

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "{% url 'posApp:update_order_item_quantity' order.id 0 %}".slice(0, -2) + itemId + "/",
                    data: {
                        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
                        'quantity': quantity
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response.success) {
                            var itemElement = $('#item-' + response.order_item_id);
                            var totalPriceWithTax = parseFloat(response.total_price_with_tax);
                            var totalWithoutTax = parseFloat(response.total_without_tax);
                            var totalTax = parseFloat(response.total_tax);
                            var totalWithTax = parseFloat(response.total_with_tax);

                            itemElement.find('.item-total').text(totalPriceWithTax.toFixed(2));
                            $('#total-amount').text(totalWithoutTax.toFixed(2));
                            $('#total-tax').text(totalTax.toFixed(2));
                            $('#total-with-tax').text(totalWithTax.toFixed(2));
                        } else {
                            alert('Error updating item quantity.');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        alert('An error occurred: ' + error);
                    }
                });
            });


            $(document).on('click', '.remove-item', function() {
                var itemId = $(this).data('item-id');
                var orderId = $(this).data('order-id');

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "{% url 'posApp:remove_from_order' order.id 0 %}".slice(0, -2) + itemId + "/",
                    data: {
                        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response.success) {
                            $('#item-' + response.order_item_id).remove();
                            updateOrderTotals(parseFloat(response.total_without_tax), parseFloat(response.total_tax), parseFloat(response.total_with_tax));
                        } else {
                            alert('Error removing item.');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        alert('An error occurred: ' + error);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

I decided to change the template to the Django template format, as it is bellow:
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load multiply %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}
    <title>Order Details</title>
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <h1>Order {{ order.id }}</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <form id="add-item-form" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="barcode">Barcode</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="barcode" name="barcode" placeholder="Enter Barcode" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" min="1" value="1" required>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Product</button>
                </form>
                <div id="error-message" class="text-danger mt-2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2>Current Order</h2>
                <ul class="list-group" id="order-items">
                    {% for item in order.items.all %}
                        <li class="list-group-item" id="item-{{ item.id }}">
                            {{ item.product.name }} -
                            <input type="number" class="form-control d-inline item-quantity" style="width: 70px;" value="{{ item.quantity }}" min="1" data-item-id="{{ item.id }}" data-order-id="{{ order.id }}">
                            x {{ item.product.price }} + Tax: {{ item.tax_amount }} = <span class="item-total">{{ item.price|add:item.tax_amount }}</span>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove-item" data-order-id="{{ order.id }}" data-item-id="{{ item.id }}">Remove</button>
                        </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
                <p class="mt-3"><strong>Total (before tax):</strong> <span id="total-amount">{{ order.total_amount }}</span></p>
                <p class="mt-3"><strong>Total Tax:</strong> <span id="total-tax">{{ order.total_tax_amount }}</span></p>
                <p class="mt-3"><strong>Total (with tax):</strong> <span id="total-with-tax">{{ order.total_amount_with_tax }}</span></p>
                <form action="{% url 'posApp:checkout' order.id %}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Checkout</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Function to update order totals in the UI
            function updateOrderTotals(totalWithoutTax, totalTax, totalWithTax) {
                $('#total-amount').text(totalWithoutTax.toFixed(2));
                $('#total-tax').text(totalTax.toFixed(2));
                $('#total-with-tax').text(totalWithTax.toFixed(2));
            }

            // Add product to order
            $('#add-item-form').on('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var barcode = $('#barcode').val();
                var quantity = parseInt($('#quantity').val());
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "{% url 'posApp:add_to_order' order.id %}",
                    data: {
                        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
                        'barcode': barcode,
                        'quantity': quantity
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response.success) {
                            var itemElement = $('#item-' + response.order_item_id);
                            if (itemElement.length) {
                                // Update existing item
                                itemElement.find('.item-quantity').val(response.quantity);
                                itemElement.find('.item-total').text((response.quantity * parseFloat(response.price)).toFixed(2));
                            } else {
                                // Add new item
                                var itemHTML = '<li class="list-group-item" id="item-' + response.order_item_id + '">' +
                                    response.product_name + ' - ' +
                                    '<input type="number" class="form-control d-inline item-quantity" style="width: 70px;" value="' + response.quantity + '" min="1" data-item-id="' + response.order_item_id + '" data-order-id="{{ order.id }}">' +
                                    ' x ' + parseFloat(response.price).toFixed(2) + ' + Tax: ' + parseFloat(response.tax_amount).toFixed(2) + ' = <span class="item-total">' + (response.quantity * parseFloat(response.price)).toFixed(2) + '</span>' +
                                    '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove-item" data-order-id="{{ order.id }}" data-item-id="' + response.order_item_id + '">Remove</button>' +
                                    '</li>';
                                $('#order-items').append(itemHTML);
                            }
                            updateOrderTotals(parseFloat(response.total_without_tax), parseFloat(response.total_tax), parseFloat(response.total_with_tax));
                            $('#barcode').val('');
                            $('#quantity').val(1);
                            $('#error-message').text('');
                        } else {
                            $('#error-message').text(response.error);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        $('#error-message').text('An error occurred: ' + error);
                    }
                });
            });

            // Update item quantity
            $(document).on('change', 'input.item-quantity', function() {
                var itemId = $(this).data('item-id');
                var orderId = $(this).data('order-id');
                var quantity = parseInt($(this).val());

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "{% url 'posApp:update_order_item_quantity' order.id 0 %}".slice(0, -2) + itemId + "/",
                    data: {
                        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
                        'quantity': quantity
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response.success) {
                            var itemElement = $('#item-' + response.order_item_id);
                            var totalPriceWithTax = parseFloat(response.total_price_with_tax);
                            var totalWithoutTax = parseFloat(response.total_without_tax);
                            var totalTax = parseFloat(response.total_tax);
                            var totalWithTax = parseFloat(response.total_with_tax);

                            itemElement.find('.item-total').text(totalPriceWithTax.toFixed(2));
                            updateOrderTotals(totalWithoutTax, totalTax, totalWithTax);
                        } else {
                            alert('Error updating item quantity.');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        alert('An error occurred: ' + error);
                    }
                });
            });

            // Remove item from order
            $(document).on('click', '.remove-item', function() {
                var itemId = $(this).data('item-id');
                var orderId = $(this).data('order-id');

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "{% url 'posApp:remove_from_order' order.id 0 %}".slice(0, -2) + itemId + "/",
                    data: {
                        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response.success) {
                            $('#item-' + response.order_item_id).remove();
                            updateOrderTotals(parseFloat(response.total_without_tax), parseFloat(response.total_tax), parseFloat(response.total_with_tax));
                        } else {
                            alert('Error removing item.');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        alert('An error occurred: ' + error);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock content %}

Unfortunately, this template does not working. It's throwing this error message:Method Not Allowed (POST): /order/57/
Method Not Allowed: /order/57/
For more details, here is my views for the order details:
class AddToOrderView(View):
    def post(self, request, order_id):
        order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=order_id)
        barcode = request.POST.get('barcode')
        quantity = int(request.POST.get('quantity', 1))

        try:
            product = Product.objects.get(barcode=barcode)
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({'success': False, 'error': 'Product does not exist in the database.'})

        # Check if the product already exists in the order
        order_item, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(order=order, product=product)
        if created:
            order_item.quantity = quantity
        else:
            order_item.quantity += quantity
        order_item.save()

        # Recalculate totals
        total_without_tax = sum(item.price for item in order.items.all())
        total_tax = sum(item.tax_amount for item in order.items.all())
        total_with_tax = total_without_tax + total_tax
        total_price_with_tax = order_item.price + order_item.tax_amount

        return JsonResponse({
            'success': True,
            'order_item_id': order_item.id,
            'product_name': product.name,
            'quantity': order_item.quantity,
            'price': product.price,
            'tax_amount': order_item.tax_amount,
            'total_without_tax': total_without_tax,
            'total_tax': total_tax,
            'total_with_tax': total_with_tax,
            'total_price_with_tax': total_price_with_tax,
            'is_existing_item': not created
        })

Actually,the existing solutions for similar case does not solving my issue.
Thanks
This is the url posApp for more details.
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    home, CategoryListView, ProductListView, CreateOrderView, OrderDetailView,
    AddToOrderView, RemoveFromOrderView, AddCategoryView, AddProductView,
    CheckoutView, CheckoutCompleteView, update_order_item_quantity, OrderListView, 
    CreateStripePaymentIntentView, CaptureStripeTerminalPaymentView,restock_product, 
    product_list, stock_history
)

app_name = 'posApp'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name='home'),
    path('categories/', CategoryListView.as_view(), name='category_list'),
    path('category/<int:category_id>/products/', ProductListView.as_view(), name='product_list'),
    path('order/create/', CreateOrderView.as_view(), name='create_order'),
    path('order/<int:order_id>/', OrderDetailView.as_view(), name='order_detail'),
    path('order/<int:order_id>/add/', AddToOrderView.as_view(), name='add_to_order'),
    path('order/<int:order_id>/remove/<int:item_id>/', RemoveFromOrderView.as_view(), name='remove_from_order'),
    path('order/<int:order_id>/update/<int:item_id>/', update_order_item_quantity, name='update_order_item_quantity'),
    path('order/<int:order_id>/checkout/', CheckoutView.as_view(), name='checkout'),
    path('order/<int:order_id>/checkout/complete/', CheckoutCompleteView.as_view(), name='checkout_complete'),
    path('orders/', OrderListView.as_view(), name='order_list'),
    path('category/add/', AddCategoryView.as_view(), name='add_category'),
    path('product/add/', AddProductView.as_view(), name='add_product'),
    path('order/<int:order_id>/create_stripe_payment_intent/', CreateStripePaymentIntentView.as_view(), name='create_stripe_payment_intent'),
    path('order/<int:order_id>/capture_stripe_terminal_payment/', CaptureStripeTerminalPaymentView.as_view(), name='capture_stripe_terminal_payment'),

    path('products/', product_list, name='product_list'),  # Product list view
    path('product/<int:product_id>/restock/', restock_product, name='restock_product'),  # Restock product
    # Stock History URL
    path('product/<int:product_id>/history/', stock_history, name='stock_history'),    
]


Care to share the URL namespace posApp? Many views are used from there with the exact same method POST. Remember to share all the views along with the entire URL namespace.

Most likely you are calling something other than AddToOrderView.

Make sure that the URL in your frontend matches exactly with the URL in your urls.py file. Check if a trailing / is needed at the end of the URL. Sometimes, the Method Not Allowed error can occur due to discrepancies in trailing slashes in the URL.

Please, I edited my question and add the url as you requested. Thank for taking a look on it.

from what you shared, you’re submitting data to order view which is not supposed to receive post data. In form where you set method=‘post’, set also action=‘url-to-receive-post-data-to-process’

Can you please have a look on my URL, so that you can be much more clear in order for me to be able to solve the issue? Thanks

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
